# Sync Full Archive node from snap sync node in a geth based Private Blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum

I have questions about the Geth sync mode.
So, I have a private blockchain with POW consensus and currently, it is running with 1 snap sync node, and 1 full archive node.
can I recover all data from the snap sync node? if my archive node server is corrupted or deleted?

does the snap sync node have all data?

Comment: if any node is corrupted or deleted you can reconstruct the blockchain if you have export data. There is a command called "export" in geth, if you backup your chain periodically you will be able to reconstruct it any time, even if all of your nodes are deleted

Comment: so, if you are running a private chain it is highly recommended to export the chain. Since there are little nodes of yours chain available you have to rely more on the full backup feature

Comment: there is no "snap sync " node, there are only "Archival" and "Full" nodes. The node that has synced via "snap sync" feature has all the data of the chain and you can turn it off, "export" all its data and recreate the data on any number of copies

Comment: If an node has synced via "snap sync" it will have all the blocks (up to the latest) and this is where all the data is kept. You don't need the state, the state can be recreated from blocks

Comment: even if the node got corrupted , you still could export the data via export command, provided that the damage is not done at the device level (i.e. there are no bad blocks on the disk), I mean , if there is some logical corruption, like a bug in `geth` or if you did unclean shutdown. the data is recoverable